CPU jumps vs Single threaded process
We have bee running Pgbouncer instance on centos7 for PostgreSQL connection pooling. Recently after routing some connections through pgbouncer we have been noticing high CPU jumps associated with pgbouncer VM. Zabbix monitoring tool shows high context switches as well as interrupts but very low in terms of CPU load and usage. The VM running pgbouncer is exclusively for itself with 2 core however pgbouncer is a single threaded process.
Does single threaded process associated with high context switches? Is there any way we can reduce this CPU jumps?
Additional info:
The VM is running on Azure with hyper-threading enabled, it's basically 1 core with two threads. Does disabling hyper-thread resolve this? Would it introduce any other problem in a system exclusively for pgbouncer?
